# Interactive Grid validation before saving in Oracle Apex

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

i have 2 tables in my database, purchase_order and purchase_order_details.
`purchase_order` has a column `max_amount` representing the total amount of money that can be spent in that order, and `purchase_order_details` has `item_id` and `price`, before saving this condition `max_amount<sum(price)` has to be met.

what i need is to calculate the old sum, add the new inserted sum and verify that it is less than the allowed max amount.

So i wrote this pl/sql validation function

```
DECLARE
mx_amount number;
sum_prices number;
BEGIN
select max_amount into mx_amount from purchase_order where id=:P11_ID;
select sum(price) into sum_prices from purchase_order_details where order_id=:P11_ID;
IF mx_amount<=sum_prices then return true; 
else return false;
END IF;
END;
```

the problem with this code is that the new inserted values are not in the database yet so it always returns true and i don't how to reference IG data to do something like :

```
DECLARE
NEW_PRICES number;
BEGIN
select sum(:price) into NEW_PRICES from dual;
```

with `:price` being the IG price column for each row.
so how can i calculate the old sum, add the new inserted sum and verify that it is less than the allowed max amount, so for example if i only have 1000$, the user cannot buy 1500$ so i have to check if the sum is less or equal to validate the insertion.

Comment: Is that meant to be "interactive" or "interaction"?

Comment: what do you mean?
what i need is something that tells the user : " you have exceeded the amount that is allowed, you need to reduce your order" and won't let him validate IG data until he corrects that error.

Comment: "Interactie" in the title could be "interaction" misspelled by a Dutch person, or "interactive" by anyone who cannot find the _v_ key.

Comment: Have a look at [this blog](https://pretius.com/blog/interactive-grid-duplicate-values/). It shows how to prevent duplicate values in an IG. You could probably use a similar approach for your issue to validate the sum.

Answer (score 0):

if sequence is being shown in IG i.e the primary key, column SEQ.

```
DECLARE
mx_amount number;
sum_prices number;
BEGIN
select max_amount into mx_amount from purchase_order where id=:P11_ID;
select sum(price)+:price into sum_prices from purchase_order_details where order_id=:P11_ID and seq<>:seq;
IF mx_amount<=sum_prices then return true; 
else return false;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: purchase_order_details has 'ID' as a primary-key and has a foreign key 'order_id', purchase_order has a primary-key 'ID' , im joining these 2 table by purchase_order.id=purchase_order_details .order_id

Comment: i need to know the sum before inserting because the user cannot exceed the amount of money available, so for example if i only have 1000$, the user cannot buy 1500$ so i have to check if the sum is less or equal to validate the insertion

Comment: how is the ID value inserted/ calculated in purchase order details table?
is it a sequence? asking because if there is a way to identify which ID you are planning to replace while calculating new sum and was present in OLD sum.
you can pass it in select query while calculating the sum where order_id = :P11_ID and ID<>'ID to be replaced'

Comment: yes, as sequence (by default on null).

Comment: but note that there 3 cases here: 
- inserting when there are no purchases yet.
- inserting when there are already some old purchases.
- editing old purchases.
in all of these cases i have to verify the new amount before insertion.

Comment: now in this case, are you showing this sequence in the ig?

Comment: i'm using the ID, it is hidden though.

Comment: try above query, replace SEQ with ID

Answer (score 0):

How about adding an 'amount_spent' column to the purchase order table, and adding a check constraint on it being the amount less-equal than the max_amount.
Then in your APEX page, you take care of having 2 models in the page (which you might have already). Before save, you calculate the amount spent and update the purchase order model. You execute the save with apex.model.save(): this will send the updates of both models in 1 transaction.
By this approach, not only you will get a contraint violation on the transaction when the amount spent is too high, but also you will get an error if meanwhile another user has updated the purchase order lines.
In case the purchase orders in the DB can also be updated via other means external to APEX, this solution will not suffice, and you need a more heavy solution in the database as to fully protect it.
The above solution also assumes you can load all purchase order lines for the order into the model and calculate the total amount by iterating the model records.